# Inspect element Chrome CSS changes lost on refresh

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

This might be a weird question but i do this often enough that I'm going to ask, When i am making some adjustments to the look of my web page via CSS I often just inspect element and put in the changes and then when it looks right i copy and paste those changes back to my css sheet and save (the css files are located on my remote server uploaded with FTP), occasionally i accidently refresh the page without the css properly copied and loose my css, is there a way to "get back those changes after refreshing my page or is there a tool i could use to automatically save/back them up so they don't get lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hack styles into pages and copy them over in the same way that you do.

To answer your question, I don't know of any way to get the changes back (clearing changes is the whole point of 'refreshing'), but here are 2 alternative options:

1. Make smaller changes (I try to focus on a single element/node at a time)
2. There are a lot of chrome extensions that tackle this type of problem

   - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-autosave/mlejngncgiocofkcbnnpaieapabmanfl?hl=en

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to work where is my local file auto saved? (i am using windows 10 no server)

Comment: I've never used that extension (like I said, I just make smaller changes), but [the documentation](https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave) seems to be pretty good

Comment: Gah, I'm in the same boat as you two. I was hoping for more of a solid solution, preferably something like being warned before leaving/refreshing with styles still inside the inspector stylesheet would be great.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with DevTools Workspaces: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/workspaces/

You can only make changes to CSS in a file, not inline CSS or HTML markup.

Comment: The link is broken. Please add what you find relevant about links you put in answers.

Comment: I updated the link. I found the new link by searching for "DevTools Workspaces".