Is there a way to have web dev tools (like chrome debugger) save changes to the source code?
Web dev tools show you the code and source files in your web pages. They also let you type code into the source file. Is there a way to save those changes to the file?
For example, let's say I have mypage.html and myjavacript.js or myjavascript.ts and I am viewing it in the browser with web dev tools open. I then add console.log("hello world") to myjavascript.js. FYI The source code field is editable. I then click a button to save those changes. Then myjavascript.js is updated on the filesystem. I return to vscode and the javascript is updated.
Is this possible?
Currently, if I change the contents of the source file in web dev tools and use CTRL + S to save, an icon appears and the tool tip says, "Changes to this file were not saved to the filesystem".
The other question asks how to handle the error. My question asks how to save to the file system. Though some answers overlap it's not the same.
Possible answer (SO is not letting me add an answer because someone on this site closed this question):
It seems the answer is to add the source folder here:

Reopen this question so I can add an answer to, "How to save changes from web dev tools"
Update:
It doesn't work sometimes. Then one time I noticed a message across the top of the screen, "Allow dev tools to save to the file system? Warning, this could reveal sensitive information." with a yes or no option. Wait a second? What is this about? Why? I only want to allow web dev tools to save files to the hard drive. Why would this option be risky? Or why would you allow this option to be risky?
I have tried to enable this feature since.

that would mean that the web page in the browser is able to access (write) the (local) file system. And what to do if the HTML/JS is fetched from a web server, you also want to update the server, and what if the page is build with a lot of Ajax calls.

@rioV8 not the same thing. the web page is not saving the file. the developer is making changes in the web dev tool / chrome debugger editor and then using the save dialog box with their browser. if you open a browser now and you go to File > Save as you are saving the web page files to the file system. There is no reason the browser should not be able to write files to the file system if you want it and especially if the files are a local web project already

@starball Sometimes it doesn't work. I updated the question. also, it is nice to have an answer to this question rather than, "Why doesn't this specific thing work?" I'll add an answer myself later

still think this must be a duplicate of something. Ex. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45639470/11107541. there's no way this question at its core is new, unless it's isolated to the question about risks, and even that at a higher level is probably a duplicate of something.

Use the workspaces feature. Read the full instructions and list of limitations (Ex. build toolchain transformations and source maps, editing HTML via sources panel vs elements panel) there. Open devtools, go to "Sources" > "Workspace", add a folder mapping, and then when prompted to allow devtools to access the directory, make sure you remove any sensitive info from that directory (Ex. secrets files), or are okay with the risk of allowing devtools to access it, and then allow it.

Why would this option be risky?

Depending on how much an application in any nesting of runtimes is sandboxed from the rest of your system / enclosing runtimes, running any arbitrary application is "risky".
